# Convert only a part of column into numeric

Tags: r, for-loop

My data frame looks like

```
df <- data.frame("info" = c("food", "number", "price"), 
"a" = c("Melon","1.84+", NA), 
"b" = c("Berry" ,"4.49+", "44"), 
"c" = c("Orange", NA, "4.40"), 
"d" = c("Apple","9", "1.94+"))`
```

What I want is to remove all plus signs from the numbers, and change them to numeric.

I've tried

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
     for (j in 1:ncol(df)){
          if (i > 1 & j > 1){
              df[[i,j]] <<- as.numeric(as.character(gsub("\\+", "", df[[i,j]])))
}}}
```

After running the above code, plus signs are successfully removed, but when I check the class for numeric cells, R gives back `"character"`.

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas on this? 
Any hep would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot mix types in a vector. They all have to be the same or they will be coerced. Try `c("a", 1)`

Comment: The columns got other rows with `character`. You cannot have both `numeric` and `character` in same column.

Comment: I would suggest transposing `df` so that you have columns of the same type.

Comment: The dataframe is a very odd structure. `food`, `number` and `price` should probably be your column headers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your data-orientation is wrong. You can covert your data.frame in more meaning format and then change columns to numeric. Using `gather` and `spread` you can re-arrange data.

One option using `tidyverse` can be as:

```
library(tidyverse)


df %>% gather(key, value, - info) %>%
  spread(info, value) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(number:price), funs(as.numeric(gsub("\\+", "",.))))

#Result -- Its same data but represented in slightly different way.

#   key   food number price
# 1   a  Melon   1.84    NA
# 2   b  Berry   4.49 44.00
# 3   c Orange     NA  4.40
# 4   d  Apple   9.00  1.94
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame("info" = c("food", "number", "price"), 
                 "a" = c("Melon","1.84+", NA), 
                 "b" = c("Berry" ,"4.49+", "44"), 
                 "c" = c("Orange", NA, "4.40"), 
                 "d" = c("Apple","9", "1.94+"))
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R you can do something like:

```
 cbind(nn=names(df[-1]),read.table(text=gsub("\\+","",do.call(paste,data.frame(t(df)))),h=T))
  nn   food number price
1  a  Melon   1.84    NA
2  b  Berry   4.49 44.00
3  c Orange     NA  4.40
4  d  Apple   9.00  1.94
```